# An exported eclipse plugin project throws ../build.xml does not exist error

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, build.xml

I am trying to export an Eclipse plugin project as a standalone program (RCP). The program runs fine on eclipse but when I export it, the following error is thrown. Basically, the stacktrace shows that there is no build.xml file.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:513)
at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.start(AntRunner.java:600)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

Caused by: Buildfile: /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/build.xml does not exist
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.parseBuildFile(InternalAntRunner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:537)
    ... 19 more
```

In my eclipse project, I autogenerated the build.xml file and I confirmed that it exists in the project. Question is why is it not getting exported along with other required plugin files and folders? A penny for your thoughts?

Comment: I had the same issue but in net beans. Solved by doing a rebuild. Have you tried that at all?

Comment: @SteveGreen - I tried that. Still no good.

Comment: :( um. Have you stepped through the XML to make sure all tags are closed etc and nothing's gone pear shaped there?

Comment: I noticed that after I export the project, the build.xml file disappears and that I have to regenerate it. Something fishy?

Comment: Definitely fishy. Hopefully another wiser than moi can help:)

Comment: Have you included it in binary build or source build in your plugin.xml?

Comment: @PradeepSimha: I have added it to the binary build.

Comment: @nick-s: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=120840